# View in a CRUD application giving- syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, syntax-error, crud

In my contactlist CRUD application, all the contacts are shown properly when i type the following URL:  localhost/contact

However, I want to have two options for each contact- either to update the information or to delete the record. So once i click on contact,say- "Chetan", i want to go to a 'showmain' page with two options- Update(linking me to an update page) and Delete(linking me to a del page).

My controller is as follows:-

```
class ContactController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @contacts=Contact.find(:all)

      respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @contacts }
    end
  end


  def show
    @contact=Contact.find(params[:id])
  end

  def del
    @contact=Contact.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @contact=Contact.new
  end

  def create
     @contact=Contact.new(params[:contact])
    if @contact.save!
      redirect_to :action => "index"
    else
      render :action => "new"
    end
  end

  def showmain

      respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json 
  #  @contact=Contact.new(params[:contact])
  end

  def update
    @contact=Contact.find(params[:id])
    @contact.attributes= params[:contact]
    @contact.save!
    redirect_to :action => "index" 
  end

  def delete
    @contact=Contact.find(params[:id])
    @contact.destroy
    redirect_to :action => "index"
  end
  end
  end
```

And my showmain.html.erb page where i am getting the syntax error(showmain.html.erb:14: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end) is as follows:-

```
<h1>Do you want to Update or Delete the Attributes? </h1>

<ul>
    <li>
        <%= link_to "Update" ,:action=>'show',:id => @contact -%>
    </li>

    <li>
        <%= link_to "Delete" ,:action=>'del',:id => @contact -%>
    </li>   
</ul>
<% end %>

<p>
    <%= link_to "Back", {:action => 'index'} -%>
</p>
```

Need some help to remove the error..

My show.html.erb is as follows:-

```
<h1>View/Edit Contact</h1>

 <% link_to "Update" , contact_path(@contact) do |f| -%

  <%= f.label :first_name %>:
  <%= f.text_field :first_name %><br />

  <%= f.label :last_name %>:
  <%= f.text_field :last_name %><br />

  <%= f.label :address %>:
  <%= f.text_field :address %><br />


  <%= f.label :city %>:
  <%= f.text_field :city %><br />


  <%= f.label :state %>:
  <%= f.text_field :state %><br />


  <%= f.label :country %>:
  <%= f.text_field :country %><br />


  <%= f.label :phone %>:
  <%= f.text_field :phone %><br />


  <%= f.label :email %>:
  <%= f.text_field :email %><br />

  <%= f.submit "Update" %>

<% end %>

<p>
    <%= link_to 'Back', {:action => 'index'} %>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def showmain

  respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json 
      #  @contact=Contact.new(params[:contact])
  end #Close respond_to
end # Close the showmain
```

Comment: Thanks Victor..this was indeed the problem. I corrected the error and landed up with a new one related to active record while selecting options for both Update and Delete:(